# how to find file in a set of directories using its ID

Tags: java, python, c++, file

I have a set of *4040* directories. Every directory contains *5000* files. Files are identified by their numbers.

```
 - Directory 1 contains files from 1.txt to 5000.txt
 - Directory 2 contains files from 5001.txt to 10,000.txt
 - Directory 3 contains files from 10001.txt to 15000.txt
 - ....
 - Directory 4040 contains files from 20200001.txt to 20204083.tx
```

I want to search for every file by it's ID. For example: if i type x = 10 it should open file 10.txt from directory 1. As input I have the **file ID** and the **path**. what **formula** that I can use to do this.

---

I tried the divide the **ID** by the **size** of the set. 
For example If I divide **14,000** by **4040** I get **3.4** which is wrong. **14,000** should be in set **2**.

Comment: "14,000 should be in set 2" is this correct? I think it will be in set 3. to find set you can use Math.floor function.

Comment: oh Damn it Yes YES you are right. I start the count by 0 not by 1 sheesh. deserve a minus on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integer division,

```
int file_id = ...;
int directory_id = (file_id - 1) / 5000 + 1;
```

Comment: In Python 3 you'll get a float result. You need the `//` floor division operator (or apply `int()` to the result )

Comment: @nigel222 Indeed. The question was only tagged C++ when I wrote the answer.